# Selecting middle row fails with just one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I wrote a query which selects the middle row from a table:

```
with records as(select row_number() over(order by someKey) as 'row', *
                from MyTable)
select *
from records
where row=(select (count(*)/2) from records)
```

This works fine except for the case in which `MyTable` has just one row, in which it returns an empty dataset. I supposed this was because in that particular case, 1/2 got truncated to zero. So I tried `ceiling( count(*)/2 )`, but I got the same result. How do I get `count(*)/2` to use float arithmetic?

Comment: you could try to use a *CASE WHEN* in your subquery

Comment: Someone answered I should just use `2.0` insted of `2`. That worked just fine. Dunno why that answer was deleted... Is the `CASE WHEN` way the canon for cases like this one?

Comment: @dario_ramos I deleted it because I wasn't sure of the answer `:D` now its back since i tested it on sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try, the `.0` hack,

```
CEILING(COUNT(*) / 2.0)
```